# Reciprocals using Scala BigDecimal multiplication and division

Tags: java, scala

We are running into an issue where we are dividing a bigdecimal by another bigdecimal, and trying to verify it by taking the reciprocal of the divisor and multiplying the dividend.

For example, basic math would tell us that: `a / b = a * (1 / b)`

More specifically, here is what we are trying to do: `6.0075 / 0.89 = 6.0075 * (1 / 0.89) = 6.75`

Using BigDecimal for added precision, we can get the first part:

```
scala> BigDecimal(6.0075) / BigDecimal(0.89)
res1: scala.math.BigDecimal = 6.75
```

But not the second:

```
scala> BigDecimal(6.0075) * (BigDecimal(1.00) / BigDecimal(0.89))
res2: scala.math.BigDecimal = 6.749999999999999999999999999999999
```

Digging in further, we see that `BigDecimal(1.00) / BigDecimal(0.89)` is an imprecise result and that Scala's BigDecimal wrapper around Java's math.BigDecimal specifies a precision of 35 decimals with a RoundingMode of HALF_EVEN. Unfortunately, `1.00 / 0.89` has an infinite number of decimal places so using java's BigDecimal directly won't help either.

Has anyone else encountered this issue? Is there a way in either Scala or Java to handle this aside from attempting to rewrite the the expression `1.00/0.89`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no getting around the fact that a finite representation of an infinite regression will have rounding errors. (See also: [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken))

I see two possible solutions, neither of them trivial.

1. Use a Rational Numbers class to represent these values.  Every value will have both a numerator and a denominator in whole integrals. You'll need to track the GCD, but the only time you'll actually need to dived two numbers is when sending a value to the screen (or page).
2. Check each value for rounding errors (this would probably be best done via RegEx pattern matching on the`String` representation of the value) and adjust accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately there is no 100% accurate way to represent numbers with an infinite decimal expansion like `1.00/0.89` (or `1/3` for that matter) with floating point numbers. This is a limitation of finite machines trying to emulate infinite properties.

However if you only care about accuracy to a certain number of digits (like 2 if you are using currency) then you could use Java's `MathContext` and the `setScale` method:

```
scala> import java.math.{RoundingMode => RM, MathContext => MC}
import java.math.{RoundingMode=>RM, MathContext=>MC}

scala> val mc = new MC(100, RM.HALF_UP)
mc: java.math.MathContext = precision=100 roundingMode=HALF_UP

scala> val a = BigDecimal("6.0075")
a: scala.math.BigDecimal = 6.0075

scala> val b = BigDecimal("1")
b: scala.math.BigDecimal = 1

scala> val c = BigDecimal("0.89")
c: scala.math.BigDecimal = 0.89

scala> val d = (a * (b(mc) / c)).setScale(2)
d: scala.math.BigDecimal = 6.75
```

Note that I am using the string version of your doubles because they are a more precise representation (because even `0.89` cannot be represented in floating point numbers perfectly).

**EDIT**:

Inspired by @jwvh's comment about Rational Numbers I threw this basic `Rational` class together:

```
scala> :pa
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

object Rational
{
    def apply(n: BigInt, d: BigInt): Rational =
    {
        val neg_mod = if (d < BigInt(0)) BigInt(-1) else BigInt(1)
        val (n_mod, d_mod) = (neg_mod * n, neg_mod * d)
        val gcd_val = gcd(n_mod, d_mod)
        new Rational(n_mod / gcd_val, d_mod / gcd_val)
    }
    def gcd(a: BigInt, b: BigInt): BigInt = if (b == BigInt(0)) a else gcd(b, a % b)
}
class Rational(val n: BigInt, val d: BigInt)
{
    override def toString: String = if (n == BigInt(0)) "0" else if (d == BigInt(1)) s"$n" else s"$n/$d"

    def toDouble: Double = n.toDouble / d.toDouble

    def *(that: Rational): Rational = Rational(n * that.n, d * that.d)

    def /(that: Rational): Rational = Rational(n * that.d, d * that.n)

    def +(that: Rational): Rational = Rational(n * that.d + that.n * d, d * that.d)

    def -(that: Rational): Rational = this + (-that)

    def unary_- = Rational(-n, d)
}

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined object Rational
defined class Rational

scala> val a = Rational(60075, 10000)
a: Rational = 2403/400

scala> val b = Rational(1, 1)
b: Rational = 1

scala> val c = Rational(89, 100)
c: Rational = 89/100

scala> a * (b / c)
res0: Rational = 27/4

scala> (a * (b / c)).toDouble
res1: Double = 6.75
```

Answer (score -1):

You want to verify that `a / b` is equal to `a * (1 / b)`

Problem: value for `(1 / b)` might not be exact.

My workaround:
Let `u = 0.00000000000000000000000000000000001` (you say it works to 35 decimal places)
Then verify that `a / b` is at least `a * ((1 / b) - u)` and at most `a * ((1 / b) + u)`
If `a` is negative, then you will need to swap the signs of those comparisons.
This is not a perfect workaround, but I hope it will do.